# Derivative of $f(u)=\sqrt{8} \;u+\sqrt{6u}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> $$f(u)=\sqrt{8} \;u+\sqrt{6u}$$

$f(u)=\sqrt{8}\;u+(6u)^{1/2}$
$f^{\prime}(u)=\sqrt{8}+\dfrac{1}{2}(6u)^{-1/2}$
$=\sqrt{8}+3u^{-1/2}$

This was marked wrong, though. What am I doing wrong? thanks.

Comment: Why is $\frac{1}{2}6^{-1/2} = 3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right when you differentiate the $\sqrt{8}u$ part.  As you wrote, that part just becomes $\sqrt{8}$.

For the $\sqrt{6u}$ part, first, as you did, we write it as $(6u)^{\frac{1}{2}}$, and then differentiating this and using the **chain rule** (which you forgot) gives $\frac{1}{2}(6u)^{-\frac{1}{2}}(6) = 3(6u)^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{3}{\sqrt{6u}}$.

What you seemed to do was say $\frac{1}{2}(6u)^{-\frac{1}{2}} = 3u^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.  You can't multiply the $\frac{1}{2}$ and the $6$ together because the $6$ is being raised to the $-\frac{1}{2}$ power.  Also, you forgot the chain rule when differentiating.

So, $f'(u) = \sqrt{8} + \frac{3}{\sqrt{6u}}$.  Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 thanks, I solved it without the chain rule because we didn't learn the chain rule yet. Is there a way to solve it without the Chain rule? thanks

Comment: @user437158 I'm not sure, but I don't think so.  You are trying to differentiate $\sqrt{6u}$.  This is a composition of functions, where $f(u) = \sqrt{u}$ and $g(u) = 6u$ (i.e., $f(g(u)) = \sqrt{6u}$).  To find the derivative of a composition of functions, you differentiate the outside function, then multiply that by the derivative of the inside function.  So, $(f(g(u)))' = f'(g(u)) g'(u)$ (this is the chain rule).  It's weird that they gave you this problem without teaching you the chain rule first.